# How to I add a "confirmation on close" option to an android AVD

Tags: virtual-machine, android

I have unfortunately gotten into the habit of clicking on the X to close the android emulator (AVD) when I really wanted to just minimize it or something - can I make it do a "are you sure" pop-up, or perhaps a minimize to taskbar instead (like how Skype works - the X won't make it close, just go away).

Being a virtual machine, it takes a bit of time to get back up and running, so a better-than-nothing solution of where it re-launches itself would also be acceptable (but also with a way of shutting it down for good.. when the need arises).